# change json key name [ json generated using json_encode ]

Tags: php, json

I am generating json from an array using `json_encode()`, it's working properly, but it uses the key:value from the array, as usual. but I want to change the name of the key only in the json output.. is it possible to do it ? or should I prepare the json key:values myself manually ?

Example:

```
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

O/P

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

I want .

```
{"foo":1,"something":2,"bar":3,"foo":4,"baz":5}
```

edit : I cannot edit the original array..( generated using framweork)

Comment: where do the foo something bar keys come from?

Comment: if you can't edit the original array, just create a new one using the original's values, then convert that to json.

Comment: it will be common for every task . I want name: , type: , size: ..and it wont change.. -- thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only if you rewrite 'm yourself. You could use:

```
$rewriteKeys = array('a' => 'foo', 'b' => 'something', 'c' => 'bar', 'd' => 'foo', 'e' => 'baz');

$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $newArr[ $rewriteKeys[ $key ] ] = $value;
}

echo json_encode($newArr);
```

Not sure if that's what you were aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

You can always `json_decode` it and then re-encode it. But it's going to be easiest if you simply prepare your keys before you encode it.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377909/php-problem-changing-key-values-recursively-in-json-array/33455904#33455904). The main idea is to consider JSON as a string and then use str_replace or preg_replace(str_replace for regexp).

There is a code for your case.

```
$mapping_array  = array('a' => 'foo', 'b' => 'something', 'c' => 'bar', 'd' => 'foo', 'e' => 'baz');

$tmp_arr =  array_map(function($k){ return '/\b'.$k.'\b/u'; }, array_keys($mapping_array));

$new_json =  preg_replace($tmp_arr, array_values($mapping_array), $old_json);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a short answer:

```
foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
    $newList[$key] = [
        'foo'   =>  $val['a'],
        'something' =>    $val['b'],
        'bar' => $val['c'],
        'foo' => $val['d'],
        'baz' => $val['e'],
    ];
}
```