# Replace column namne with custom name with json_encode

Tags: php, json, pdo

I'm bringing json_encode data from the db.

```
foreach ($rslt as $val){
  $data[] = $val; 
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

the output is `[{"column name":"dbData1"},{"column name":"dbData2"}]`

Instead of the column name can I replace it to a custom name?

expected output:

```
[{"rec":"dbData1"},{"rec":"dbData2"}]
```

Comment: `[ "newkey" => $val["oldkey"] ]`

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5917539/1129313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this :

```
foreach ($rslt as $val){
    $data[] = array('rec'=>$val['column name']); 
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array('rec' => $val["col_name"], 'rec' => $val["col_name2"]);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```