# Append counter to end of specific keys in a flat, associative array

Tags: php, arrays, key, counter, suffix

I have an array that has 4 elements with the same key names, for example:

```
{
 "Word" : "ok",
 "key_example" : "32",
 "key_example" : "23",
 "key_example" : "21",
 "key_example" : "67"
}
```

Is there any easy way that I can loop through this with PHP and change the key names to be:

```
{
 "Word" : "ok",
 "key_example_1" : "32",
 "key_example_2" : "23",
 "key_example_3" : "21",
 "key_example_4" : "67"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename array keys in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605143/how-to-rename-array-keys-in-php)

Comment: It's not possible that you have the above array .. as array can not have same key

Comment: you are saying you have `an array that has 4 elements with the same key` which is not possible array key are unique

Comment: What is this then: "data" : [ {
        "unicode" : "1f910"
      }, {
        "unicode" : "1f5e3"
      }, {
        "unicode" : "1f4a9"
      } ]

Comment: is that not an array?

Comment: OMG its json format not array brother

Comment: You must be printing key somewhere, you need to add some count variable there. Show more code.

Comment: This will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5917539/2815635

Comment: It's json format bro. First convert into array using json_decode() and then go ahead.

Comment: Please update you question with exact format and with related name i means use json not array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = '[{ "unicode" : "1f910" }, { "unicode" : "1f5e3" }, { "unicode" : "1f4a9" }]';
$array = json_decode($string);
$count = 1;
$final = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $final['unicode_'.$count] = $item->unicode;
    $count++;
}
print_r($final); die;
```

if you want json then

```
$final = json_encode($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$newArray = array();
$index = 1;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array) {
        $newArray[$key . "_" . $i++] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you expect with this code is not possible, array dont have duplicate keys

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want because you will only replace the current array item value with each repeated key. But what you are trying to achieve is inline with the below code. Your keys have to be unique. It's how you fetch data from the array. They are your unique identifiers.

Here's an array :

```
array(
  "a" => "82",
  "b" => "32",
  "c" => "23",
  "d" => "21",
  "e" => "67"
);
```

You need to unset the array item and then you can set it in the array with the new key. (Heads Up! This is very inefficient. You should just build your array how you want it without using dupe keys.)

Here's how you append onto each key in the array :

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  unset($array[$key]);
  $array[$key . "_" . $i] = $value;
  $i++;
}

print_r($array);
```

Output :

```
array(
    [a_1] => 82
    [b_2] => 32
    [c_3] => 23
    [d_4] => 21
    [e_5] => 67
);
```